# Navigate to method definition in VSCode

Tags: vs-code, windows10

I am new to **VSCode**.

There is an **Apex** class like this:

```
class MyClass1{
     public static void someMethod(){
          MyClass2.someMethod2();
     }
}
```

Other class:

```
MyClass2{
     public static void someMethod2(){
     }
}
```

I used to use **Sublime Text**, which shows the possible occurrence of the method in a list while hovering the mouse and we can navigate to the method by clicking appropriate option in the list.

I tried right-clicking the `someMethod2()` call in `someMethod()`, but it was not showing any option to navigate to `someMethod2()`. It was showing below options:

[image]

In **VSCode** one option is I can open `MyClass2` and find the `someMethod2()`.

While working on `MyClass1`, how can I directly navigate to `someMethod2()`?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for it, you can right-click on the method name and then 'Go to Definition'. This also works for Classes and Variables.

But there is a problem, this works well for the class's internal members but not external class's members.

But again, this works on the External classes.

***Edit:*** As suggested by @Keith, On a Mac, holding down the command key results in a hyperlink appearing (if available)
[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning that e.g. on a Mac, holding down the command key results in a hyperlink appearing (if available).

Comment: @KeithC thanks for the info, I was unaware about that. So what that hyperlink refers to?

Comment: Clicking on it is a quick way to "Go to Definition".

Comment: @rahulgawale I am not able to see ** Go to Definition** when right-clicked the method name.
When click by pressing ctrl, the method does not turn into hyperlink.

Comment: @वरुण The command button thing works only on Mac, what is the version of your VS Code?

Comment: These are my VSCode version details:
Version: 1.36.1 (user setup)
Date: 2019-07-08T22:59:35.033Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362
I am using it on Windows 10.

Comment: @वरुण may be you can try reseting everything

Comment: I have reset both `setting.json` for user and workspace but pressing CTRL is not converting the method name to hyperlink.

Comment: @वरुण CTRL thing dont work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the option "Go to Definition" didn't appear in my vscode.

[image: No link]

After a long time tinkering with the settings, I found that the problem was in pointing out the **"Java Home"**.

So, maybe these steps will help you:

1. Go to Settings ("Ctrl + ," on Windows/Linux) and search for "**java home**" [image: Settings]
2. Make sure you point to the **Java home folder** and not the executable, as in the example above. Check if the **java version** installed on your computer is **11 or 8**. In my case, the path was: */usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/* because I use Linux. For your OS, check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/getting-started/java-setup/).[image: Right path]
3. Reload the window ("Ctrl + R" on Windows/Linux) [image: Reload]
4. Now "Go to Definition" is working as it should:

[image: Success 1][image: Success 2]

For more information on configuring java in vscode, please visit the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/getting-started/java-setup/).

I hope I've helped. See ya!!