# Go to definition not always working in VS Code

Tags: apex, visualstudiocode

When I'm developing Java code, I frequently Cmd-Click on Mac or Ctrl-Click on Windows to go to the definition of a method, class, constructor, etc. however when I'm developing Salesforce APEX code it only works some of the time.

It seems to work on some methods (ones the same class seem to work reliably but other classes are more hit and miss) and class definitions seem to work most of the time. Methods in a super-class never work as far as I can tell.

Is the Salesforce VS Code extension just broken or is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: Just for clarity - I'm not talking about issues like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299390/unable-to-navigate-code-path-for-a-specific-project-in-vs-code because in my case some parts work and some don't and they are completely reliable, if a Ctrl-clicking reference has worked it always works and others will never work - I'm just not clear which do and which don't.

Comment: The ticket has been confirmed as a bug and hopefully will be fixed. https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4293

Answer (score 0):

I would run an `SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions` to make sure all definitions are imported.

Also check that your Java runtime for the Apex language service is configured correct in Apex Extensions settings as shown below

[image]

Also, you can try deleting the cache of the APEX Language Server which is located at `PROJECT_DIR/.sfdx/tools/apex.db`

If you still see an issue open a ticket [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues)

Comment: "Refresh SObject Definitions" just silently fails for me - the UI says it's still running but it doesn't seem to be and nothing changed after 15 hours.

Comment: It seems to run `sfdx sobject definitions refresh` but if I run that on the command line it says "Warning: sobject is not a sfdx command."

Comment: That could be cause for issues you are seeing! Open an issue in the GitHub repo shared in the answer

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4293

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on clearing APEX Language Server cache. The directory has changed slightly. "To clear the Apex Language Server’s indexing, delete the `PROJECT_DIR/.sfdx/tools/<Salesforce Release>` directory and restart VS Code." - [Reset APEX Indexing](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/language-server#reset-apex-indexing)